# From SQL Server Express to SQL Server 2012 Standard and SSMS upgrade

Tags: sql-server, express, ssms

I initially install SQL Server 2012 Express and recently upgraded to SQL Server 2012 Standard edition.

Now I need to upgrade SSMS since the Express edition does not have the Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

I tried different options in setup of Standard edition, but nothing helped, I am still missing Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

Regards,

Comment: Hate to say it..  MSFT Support or use your VLC to get it from the Microsoft site.

Comment: THank you, Leptonator! What is VLC?

Comment: Volume Licensing Center..